# C++ string, test if [0] is space, issues

Tags: c++, string

i am a beginner trying to learn some simple concepts in C++, im having issues with string manipulation atm:

```
do {
    cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    getline (cin,name);
} while (name.empty() == true && name[0] != ' ');
```

As i understand it, 0 is the first occurence in the array? Yet i get a "Out of range error", when running the code and entering ' '.

Comment: If `name` is empty then there is no `name[0]`...

Comment: If `name` is empty, `name[0]` is an out-of-bounds access...

Comment: `x == true` is equivalent to `x` for any `bool` expression `x`.

Answer (score 7):

Since your code uses `&&`, it would not check the second part of the condition unless the first one is `true`, i.e. only empty strings would be checked for the initial character being a space, which is an undefined behavior. What you need is an `||`, like this:

```
do {
    cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    getline (cin,name);
} while (name.empty() || name[0] == ' ');
```

Note that there is no need to compare a return value of a `bool` function to `true`, because the comparison is going to succeed only when the expression is already `true`.

Comment: ty, yet it exits the loop on a whitespace hmm

Comment: @JohnDOe Oops, I kept `!=`, it should be an `==`. It should work now.